# How can i use the android numeric wheel?

Tags: android, view, numbers

i want to use the android-wheel in my App to set a number. What i have to do? How i call the view in the xml-file and in the Java-file.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What exactly do you want? Which wheel? Pictures? Your code? 
Something like: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-timepicker.html ?

Comment: like this http://android-devblog.blogspot.com/2010/05/wheel-ui-contol.html

Comment: where i get the class NumericWheel?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is the Android NumberPicker widget:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html